# serving blob giving 404 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm trying to serve a blob from a blobKey that I've stored in a db.Model as a blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty() and I'm unsure of how to to this properly as my current method gives a 404. I am storing the blobKey value by taking the 'rewritten' request using the regular `self.request.get('file_field')`

the contents of the key look like this in the SDK console:

```
Content-Type: video/mp4
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 475712
Content-MD5: OTY0MjY4OGI4NDgwYzVlZTI2MGJiNzg0YTA4OTIzNzY=
content-type: video/mp4
content-disposition: form-data; name="video_file"; filename="test_time.mp4"
X-AppEngine-Upload-Creation: 2012-11-10 21:41:12.973934
```

My video download handler is very standard and looks like this

```
class VideoServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

Here's how i render the url:

```
'/videos/%s' % time_data_instance.video_key.key()
```

And the url mapping:

```
('/videos/([^/]+)?', VideoServeHandler)
```

And heres the 404 error i get from the console:

```
INFO     2012-11-10 21:54:11,371 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /videos/Content-Type:%20video/mp4MIME-Version:%201.0Content-Length:%20475712Content-MD5:%20OTY0MjY4OGI4NDgwYzVlZTI2MGJiNzg0YTA4OTIzNzY=content-type:%20video/mp4content-disposition:%20form-data;%20name= HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Does anybody know what the problem might be, looking at the url in the 404 its looks as if that is incorrect but i cant find any othehr way to generate it

Update:

Heres the entire code

http://www.pastebucket.com/5163

Answer (score 0):

send_blob needs the [BlobKey](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobkeyclass), not the BlobInfo.

Just pass resource to send_blob

```
class VideoServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    self.send_blob(resource)
```

Comment: i still seem to get a 404, does the url that its trying to fetch look right to you?

Comment: I just added a link to the entire code in the main question, http://www.pastebucket.com/5163

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your request string:

```
INFO     2012-11-10 21:54:11,371 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /videos/Content-Type:%20video/mp4MIME-Version:%201.0Content-Length:%20475712Content-MD5:%20OTY0MjY4OGI4NDgwYzVlZTI2MGJiNzg0YTA4OTIzNzY=content-type:%20video/mp4content-disposition:%20form-data;%20name= HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

As far as I can see you request `/videos/Content-Type:%20video/mp4[..some garbage...]`, no wonder you get a 404 back.

Check again how you make a request URL. Definitely it does not look like this:

```
'/videos/%s' % time_data_instance.video_key.key()
```